# how to extract the word according to a suffix in python

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following code in python:

```
import re;
import nltk;
from nltk.util import ngrams;
file="C:/Python26/test.txt";
f=open("Suffix.txt",'w');
with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();
    c=0;
    for word in lines:
        if word.endswith(beta):
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n");
            c=c+1;
        else:
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n");
            c=c+1;
    print c;
    f.close()
```

This code does not give the tag "1" to those words who start with "beta", this code works well when I replace the `endswith()` with `statrswith()`, which gave the words with tag "1" who started with "beta" but does not work for `endswith()`.

I do not understand this behavior very well. Why does this happen?

**My file looks like this**

IL-2
gene
expression
and
NF-kappa
B
activation
through
CD28
requires
reactive
oxygen
production
by
5-lipoxygenase
.

Comment: did you try `word.rstrip().endswith(beta)`? You also don't need to read all the lines into memory, you can  iterate over the files object and this is python not c remove the `;`

Comment: thx, worked well and gave correct result

Comment: no worries, you also don't need to specify `"\n"` in your strip call, newlines will be removed by default, lastly use `rstrip` to remove from the end of a string

Comment: Can you give a snippet of how `suffix.txt` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `word` ends with `'\n'`. You should make sure you either strip that part of before checking, or check if it ends with `'beta\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if word.strip().endswith(beta):
```